# JS alert popup randomly showing up

Tags: javascript, axios, alert

I've got a function to post via `axios` which is supposed to popup an alert afterward to indicate if everything's OK or not.
The thing though is that it shows up randomly, whether it is a success or not.

Here is the code, let me know if more is needed.

I'm new on this site so please let me know if I'm doing wrong, should post somewhere else, or anything.

I start to wonder if my controller is the one messing with my "res"...

`````
postButton.addEventListener('click', function sendPost() {
    let formData = new FormData();
    if (document.querySelector('#actu').checked === true) {
        formData.append('title', document.getElementById('title').value);
        formData.append('authorId', localStorage.getItem('userid'));
        formData.append('category', document.querySelector('input[name="category"]:checked').value);
        formData.append('message', document.getElementById('message').value);
        formData.append('pinned', document.querySelector('input[name="pinned"]:checked').value);
        formData.append('image', document.getElementById('image_input').files[0]);
    } else if (document.querySelector('#presse').checked === true) {
        formData.append('title', document.getElementById('title').value);
        formData.append('authorId', localStorage.getItem('userid'));
        formData.append('category', document.querySelector('input[name="category"]:checked').value);
        formData.append('message', document.getElementById('message').value);
        formData.append('pinned', document.querySelector('input[name="pinned"]:checked').value);
        formData.append('image', document.getElementById('image_input').files[0]);
        formData.append('link', document.getElementById('pdf_input').files[0]);
    };

    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/user/post',
        data: formData,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token'),
        }   
    })
    .then((res) => {
        let post = document.createElement('tr');
        post.classList.add('row'+ res.data.id);
        let date = new Date(res.data.date);
        let dateParse = new Date(date).toLocaleString('fr-FR', {
            day: 'numeric', // numeric, 2-digit
            month: 'long', // numeric, 2-digit, long, short, narrow
            year: 'numeric', // numeric, 2-digit
        });    
        post.innerHTML = `
            <td class="id_row">${res.data.id}</td>
            <td class="title_row">${res.data.title}<span class="tooltiptitle">${res.data.title}</span></td>
            <td class="author_row">${res.data.authorid}</td>
            <td class="date_row">${dateParse}</td>
            <td class="array_buttons">
                <input type="button" class="edit_button" value="modifier" class="edit" onclick="edit_row(${res.data.id})">
            </td>
            <td class="array_buttons">
                <input type="button" class="delete_button" value="effacer" class="delete" onclick="delete_row(${res.data.id})">
            </td>
                `;
        if (res.data.category === 'actus') {
            tableBodyActus.appendChild(post);
        } else if (res.data.category === 'presse') {
            tableBodyPress.appendChild(post);
        };
        console.log(res.data);
        alert(res.data.message);
        location.reload();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        alert(err.response.data.message + '\n' + 'Raison invoqué : ' + err.response.data.message2)
    })
})

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

exports.postArticle = (req, res) => {
    if(req.body != null && req.files != null) {
        for (let i = 0; i < req.files.length; i++) {
            if (req.files[i].fieldname === 'image') {
                req.body.image = req.files[i].filename;
            } else if (req.files[i].fieldname === 'link') {
                req.body.link = req.files[i].filename;
            }
        }    
        let dataPost = {
            authorid: req.body.authorId,
            title: req.body.title,
            message: req.body.message,
            // Pour production :
            // image: `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/images/${req.file.filename}`, 
            image: `${req.protocol}://127.0.0.1:5500/back/datas/images/${req.body.image}`,
            link: `${req.protocol}://127.0.0.1:5500/back/datas/pdf/${req.body.link}`,
            category: req.body.category,
            pinned: req.body.pinned,
        }
        clanaDb.query('INSERT INTO actualites SET ?', dataPost,  (err, resultat) => {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err); 
                res.status(501).json({ message: 'Erreur de transmission.'});
                throw err; 
            }
            return res.status(201).json({ message: 'Merci pour votre Post !'});
        })
    } else {
    return res.status(501).json({ message: 'Erreur de validation.'});
    }
};````
`````

Comment: I dont get you... in one sentence you say `to popup an alert afterward to indicate if everything's OK or not` and exactly in the next sentence you say `it shows up randomly, wether it is a success or not` what do you actually want to achive?

Comment: Can you check that the button is not firing 'click' more than once?

Comment: I want the alert to showup and display either the res.data.message when it works or the err.response.data when it fails.
As for now, wether it works or fails, the alert shows up randomly, it means it'll works and no alert, then it works again and the alert appears, then it fails and the alert shows and it fails again but no alert.
Hopefully it's a bit more clear now :)

Comment: What do you expect from `location.reload();` after all that work?

Comment: refresh the page and come back on the admin board.

Comment: You have two alerts, one in then and another in catch... Then you say it show alert randomly, is the alert in "catch" or in "then" witch is firedup

Comment: Both. I'm suppose to have an alert, without regard of the answer ('res' or 'err'). But most of the time, no alerts pop.

Comment: When it works, I've got the formData sent to the back, I've got a console.log(req.body) which gives me all my datas, the "post.innerHTML" works fine and inside the good table but after that, the alert is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use an external library like axios to make HTTP requests. You can simply use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to achieve the same results.

You need to check the status of the response in `.then()`.

The `.catch()` block will only execute if the browser failed to send the request at all. A 400, 403, 404, 500, etc response are still considered a success.

```
...

fetch('http://localhost:3000/user/post', {
  method: 'post',
  body: formData,
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
  }
}).then(res => {
  if (res.status == 201) {
    alert('Server Handled The Request as Expected');
    return res.json();
  } else {
    alert(`Server Responded With Error: ${res.status}`);
    return false;
  }
}).then(body => {
  // process the response body
  console.log(body);
}).catch(err => {
  alert('Error Sending Request');
})
```

Additionally, in your route handler you need to remove the `return`s for your `201` and `500` results.

`return res.status(201).json(...);` and `return res.status(501).json(...);`

Should just be `res.status(201).json(...);` and `res.status(501).json(...);`

Then replace the `throw err;` line with a simple `return;`.

Comment: Hi,
thanks for the help. unfortunately, it doesn't work :(
Sometimes i get an alert 'Server Handled The Request as Expected' and sometimes not, even though the server did receive and processes as expected :(

I start to wonder if it's not something with my controller...

'''

Comment: I think that's likely. If you get no alert at all when using the code I posted then your server is not sending a response. If your add your server-side route handler code to your question it will help in narrowing down the issue.

Comment: Did it, just under the initial section :)

Comment: I've updated my answer with notes about the code you added.

Comment: One more thing I noticed: In the post request, we're checking for a 200 response but you're sending 201.

Comment: Hi,
once again, thanks for your help.
I did try to do as instructed but nothing changed.
I'll keep trying by erasing everything and adding one section at the time.
If you've got any other suggestions, they are very welcome :)

Comment: I've edited the answer to use the Fetch API instead of axios. Try that and see if it works any better.

Comment: Thanks :)
I replaced with your code using Fetch instead of Axios and i now get my alert everytime.
I can now have a feedback and work in better conditions in oder to find where is my problem and what's causing my requets to randomly works or fails :)
Thanks again, I'm gonna replace all my Axios with Fetch, you're not the first one pointing out I should do that ;).